# How to avoid cursor on EditableText widget from jumping back to the end of string once the widget loses focus

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I've an editableText widget in my flutter app.

```
      EditableText(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
            autofocus: true,
            controller: _queryCtl,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
            focusNode: tN,
            onTapOutside: (event) {
              print("tapped outside");
            },
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 175, 42),
            ),
          )
```

I've disabled input from keyboard. Instead, I've 2 textButton widgets clicking which I'll modify the text property of my textEditingController (_queryCtl as in above code). The widgets look like the following :-

```
      Row(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                addChar("2");
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Add 2',
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                addChar("3");
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Add 3',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

[Full code can be found here. It's a single main.dart file. P.S. It doesn't work as intended on web emulator. I'd suggest to reproduce on an android emulator.](https://flutlab.io/editor/229b17a5-fdc6-4b23-9241-b3766a3c8812)

Problem (Assuming I've already entered a few '2's and '3's by tapping on the TextButtons) :-

1. I place the cursor somewhere in the middle of string in
   the EditableText widget.
2. I then hit a TextButton (say 'Add
   2'). Result :- '2' will be inserted in that desired position.
3. I now hit a TextButton again. Result :- the character gets
   inserted in the end of the string, which is not desired.

[visual demonstration of the problem.](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFvjG05wic/rX8oFtyfMzME3QutfRErmA/view?utm_content=DAFvjG05wic&utm_campaign=share_your_design&utm_medium=link&utm_source=shareyourdesignpanel)

Seems like after step-2, the cursor loses it's baseOffset and resets to the length of the string. I don't want the cursor to jump to the end of the string. I want to generate the string like a regular keyboard would be able to but without using the keyboard and instead using the textButtons.

Is there a method I can stop the cursor from jumping back to the last position after step-2 ?

Comment: The solution by jmatth worked perfectly fine. However, I have a follow-up question. (I can create a new one if advised). Since I've disabled inputs from keyboard and instead I'm tapping textButtons widget to create the text on EditableText Widget, the "scroll-into-view" is gone. The EditableText widget doesn't scroll with the characters getting appended into the string. Is this problem arising because I've disabled keyboard ? If yes, how can I restore scroll-into-view or scroll-with-appending-characters action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextEditingController.text` is a convenience method that resets the selection each time it is used. If you want to control the selection then you need to set the entire `TextEditingValue`:

```dart
  void addChar(String s) {
    var insertPos = _queryCtl.selection.extentOffset;
    setState(() {
      _queryCtl.value = TextEditingValue(
        text:
            "${_queryCtl.text.substring(0, insertPos)}${s}${_queryCtl.text.substring(insertPos)}",
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _queryCtl.selection.extentOffset + s.length),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This totally worked. [Also, there's no characters property on strings, I think you meant s.length explicit]. Thanks again.

Comment: String.characters comes from the first-party characters package, which helps with navigating Unicode content. I thought it would provide more correct results in case a more complex string were inserted but I had it backwards and using characters put the cursor in the wrong location in combining character sequences. I've updated the response to just use String.length.